# Swift UIProgressView on main thread, updates property but not UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I have a UIProgressView set as an IBOutlet and I'm trying to call the setProgress method. It works just fine the first time it's called in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but nowhere else.

I'm calling it on the main thread using

```
func calculateEXP()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        //Determining playerExpBar's new value  
        let gainedEXP = Float.random(lowerEXP...upperEXP)
        let progress = (currentEXP + gainedEXP) / maxEXP

        //Setting playerExpBar's progress on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             //Set value to 0.5 for testing purposes
             self.playerExpBar.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)

             print(self.playerExpBar.progress)
        }
    }
```

}

It's printing the updated value but doesn't reflect in the UI.

Working when called in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.playerExpBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more code related with `UIProgressView `

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I added more context to where it's used. Let me know if there's any more code I can provide.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }` block outside of you global queue call?

Comment: I've tried replicating your problem but it works fine for me using your code. Are you sure that you're calling `calculateEXP()` somewhere?

Comment: @Chris I have. Neither configurations seem to work for me.

Comment: @Gordonium, calculateEXP() is getting called and printing the progress property correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just like what you said, "Swift UIProgressView on main thread, updates property but not UI", you should check your UI attribute indicator, set a value with the width constraint of your UIProgressView object.